# Rails: Anchor option and link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a `link_to` method in Rails

```
link_to("feedback", meetings_url(:anchor => "sometext"))
```

=> The above code produces:

```
<a href="/p/meeting/?scroll_to=sometext">feedback</a>
```

I thought anchor was supposed to prepend a hash paramter, something like this:

```
/p/meeting/#sometext
```

Comment: This isn't the normal Rails behavior, you should check if some gem or plugin is replacing the standard `link_to` helper.

Comment: yes yes.. You are right. I have a gem which overrides the default behavior

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I just tried in the console and I get the expected #anchor

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
# => Object
default_url_options[:host] = "localhost"
# => "localhost"
profiles_url(:anchor => "moo")
# => "http://localhost/profiles#moo"
```

What version of rails are you using?  Do yo maybe have a gem or plugin that is overriding your link_to helper?  You could create an empty rails app, and try the above test to see if something else is causing it.

Comment: Well said Jake.. I figured it out. There is some gem overriding my url helpers. !!!